# How to properly reference in C? I seem to be missing the point

Tags: c, function

So I am basically making a stack which takes in an element(10000) for example and then a priority to later sort it. So "10000 5", 5 is the priority and 10000 the element. I keep inserting the values in till a pop is called, which takes the highest priority element of the top of the stack. For some reason i get am error: "Request for member ‘priority’ in something not a structure or union." From researching the error it seems to be some kind of problem with my referencing? But i don't see where.

Comment: You want `refA->priority` or `(*refA).priority`. And `stack[i]->element = &element;` (below) will not compile either.

Comment: Use `->` to access members through a pointer, like you did a line above with `printf("%d\n",refA->element);`.

Comment: Thank you guys, a kick myself mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refA` and `refB` are pointers to structs, not structs, so you have to use `->` for referencing fields, not `.`. Like this:

```
if(refA->priority != refB->priority){
    return refB->priority - refA->priority;
} else {
    return refB->followNr - refA->followNr;
}
```

Of course you knew this, because earlier in your function, you use `->` correctly.

Comment: Of course it is, sorry a silly mistake by me. While I am here, i am probably gonna kick myself again. I also get these warnings stopping me from compiling: "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" and points to the following lines for example:      "stack[i]->element = &element;"